# Is there no mysql connector for python 2.7 on windows

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

While I see a bunch of links/binaries for mysql connector for python 2.6, I don't see one for 2.7

To use django, should I just revert to 2.6 or is there a way out ?

I'm using windows 7 64bit

django - 1.1
Mysql 5.1.50

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Does `python -m easy_install MySQL-python` work? (Assuming you have setuptools installed)?

Comment: Trying to get easy_install up & running. Learnt installing it itself is a pain on 64bit windows, since python doesn't show up in registry.

Comment: The registry key is (supposed to be) `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath`. Set the `(Default)` to `C:\Python27` (or whatever it is).

Comment: Thanks all. I couldn't wait and got it running with 2.6.6
The Registry idea sounds good ! Will give it a try someday - Thanks Seth.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.7 on specific programs:

1. sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7
2. brew install mysql@5.7
3. brew install mysql-connector-c
4. brew link --overwrite mysql@5.7
5. echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
6. sed -i -e 's/libs="$libs -l "/libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"/g' /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
7. pip install MySql-python

This solved all issues I was having running a program that ran on Python 2.7 on and older version of MySql

Answer (score 0):

Try [this one](http://lyilei.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/install-mysqldb-python/). This guy has done a good job and figured out the localization problem and gives a good link to windows binaries for what are you looking for. I hope it helps *someday*) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

this installer worked for me : 
http://www.codegood.com/archives/129